# Calculating the average of a specific row with loc, loc is not finding the row value

Tags: python, lines-of-code

I'm new to Python and stackoverflow. So please forgive any shortcomings in my posting.
I want to calculate the row average of a specific row(e.g. Bahrain) and I'm having problem achieving it.
I used df.loc but It's returning a key error with  the name of the country as it doesn't recognize the name.
My dataframe look like something like this:

```
    Country   1990  1995 2000 2005 2010 2015
0   Bahrain     5     4    3    2   1    5
1   Maldives   10     9    8    7   6    5
2   Germany    7      4    3    2   1    7
.      ....     ..    ..   ..    ..  ..  ..
.      ....     ..    ..   ..    ..  ..  ..
.      ....     ..    ..   ..    ..  ..  ..
```

I wrote this and I get an error.I got a key error with the name of row.

```py
mean=df.loc['Bahrain'].mean(axis=1)
```

I am getting the following error:

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRmXq.png)

I prefer to have an output in format of numpy.float64.

Comment: this is not how indexing works, also please post your error as text and not as image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the Bahrain at the `df["Country"]`. And also, you cannot mix text with numbers and take average. Here is how you can do it:

```
rowAverage = df[df['Country'] == 'Bahrain'].iloc[:, 1:].mean()
```

Comment: I changed it and it works now. add the axis to mean -> mean (axis=1)

Comment: ah yeah, forgot that your data is in a row instead of columns

Comment: Thank you so much Tino for your edit and the code.

Comment: Glad to help! @Amirtak. Have a nice weekend :D